# Extract values from def using groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to fetch (extract) values from def using groovy, but it doesnt allow me

```
 def rtn = rootnode.'soapenv:Body'.'qde:invokeResponse'.'qde:return'.'ns1:data';
```

RTN is having data like

```
 [{to.service.los/xsd}data[attributes={}; value=[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Application> 
<LeadRef>100</LeadRef> 
<Number>101</Number> 
<StatusCode>142</StatusCode> </Application>]]]


  def applicationNode = new XmlParser().parseText(rtn.value).'Application';
  LOG.info("Application Node ::"+applicationNode);
```

How can I fetch application object?

Answer (score 0):

`XmlParser().parseText()` returns the root.  Don't add `.'Application'`

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html#parseText%28java.lang.String%29

> Returns:
>      the root node of the parsed tree of Nodes